# Chrome Extension has been crashing suddenly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I’m developing an extension that has been crashing in production environment.

Some users showed me that the extension stops working suddenly. It still didn't work when they try again. To let it work properly te user needs to disable and enable it again.

I tried to inspect in the background to see if any error message has been shown in the console but it shows nothing at all, even the background files it’s not showing. I suppose that error messages won’t show in production environment, and in the development I can’t see the crash.

Is there anyway to debug in this situation? I have tried to put catch blocks in many points of the code that can trigger errors with no capture, but maybe I may have let it pass.

What could crash like this?

Comment: Why wouldn't there be error messages? What are you using as test environment?

Comment: I really don´t know, but it's not showing. I'm not using test environment, just my development environment: 

Google Chrome: 66.0.3359.181 (Official Version) 64 bits
OS: Mac OS X 10.11.6 

Can i simulate a production environment?

Comment: I noticed in you question that you are checking console in the element tab. Did you `console.log()` all your functions? Put something like `console.log(object_name);` **or**  `console.log(true);` **or** `console.log("Check this text out in the console tab");`

Comment: Just in some functions where can trigger a error, but didn't work.

Comment: make sure it works with one in the beginning of the `<script>`. When something doesn't work, you have to check **everything** _Once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be the truth. ~ Sir Arthur Conan Doyle_

Comment: If the background files aren't showing, it can mean you've destroyed your background page by reassigning its location to a different URL.

Comment: I'm gonna check it out wOxxOm. web-stars, can I simulate a production environment ?